# How to use Buttons as Check boxes in ant design with react js

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have created a Checkbox group in ant-design with react JS. Now, I want to use Buttons, Instead of checkboxes there. One button per one value.

Here is my code.

```
<Checkbox.Group>
   <ul className="ul-custom">
   {this.props.symptomsForCheckbox.map((symptom) => {
       return (
          <li>
              <Checkbox value={symptom.id}>
                  symptom.nameEnglish
              </Checkbox>
          </li>
       );
    })}
    </ul>
</Checkbox.Group>
```

And here it looks like

[image]

What I want is to add buttons, instead of checkboxes. The below image shows that.

[image]

And the code that I used is,

```
<Checkbox.Group>
   <ul className="ul-custom">
   {this.props.symptomsForCheckbox.map((symptom) => {
       return (
          <li>
              <Button value={symptom.id}>
                  symptom.nameEnglish
              </Button>
          </li>
       );
    })}
    </ul>
</Checkbox.Group>
```

But this doesn't work as checkboxes. Any idea for fixing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it will work if you hide the checkboxes and wrap them with a button? The button click could then check/uncheck the hidden chekcboxes. So the CheckboxGroup can use the hidden checkboxes

Comment: How do you expect checkbox behavior to be like button?

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani I want these checkboxes to look like buttons. Only the look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my creation.

You can check only one or uncheck all.

And I provided simple CSS that looks like `Radio.Button`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bsyhkm?file=index.js

I created new version with vertical and width option as you want.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bsyhkm-n7umzv?file=styled.js

Comment: This is doable. but I want the buttons to display vertically.

Comment: @AyeshNipun How about my second solution?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works as expected. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still searching, but I had the same issue and found a really good example on the sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/slwue).

It doesn't actually use any antd library, but I think it looks pretty similar, and tweaking it a bit more to appear consistent with the rest of the UI should be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CheckableTags` instead of `checkBox` to get this behavior.
[Check this example](https://ant.design/components/tag#components-tag-demo-checkable)

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try,
On button click event change the state (state = !initialstate)(ie. reverse initialstate), set initialstate to false. and then set values of checkbox based on state of button.

Comment: This is not possible. Because of the number of checkboxes are dynamic.